# Abnormal CPU usage with WS server

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

I made a websocket server using Tyrus implementation and it takes 50 % of the cpu usage but I don't know why. At first I thought it was the processes besides but after that, I wrote an extremely simple ws server after that and it is still the same...

Here is a screenshot from the resource monitor (Windows Server 2008 R2) :[image]

The server runs on a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00 Ghz with 4GB Memory
I don't know the exact architecture...

The code of the simplified ws server :

```
package wstest;

import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server;

public class Wstest {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    runServer();
}

private static void runServer() {
    Server server = new Server("localhost", 8025, "/tp", null, wsendpoint.class);
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.info("Server stopped.");
        }
    });
    try {
        server.start();
        logger.info("Server started.");
        while (true) { }
    } catch (DeploymentException ex) {
        logger.fatal(ex);
    }
}

}



package wstest;

import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@ServerEndpoint(
    value = "/test"
)
public class wsendpoint {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    logger.info("Client " + session.getId() + " connected");
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    logger.info("Client " + session.getId() + " disconnected.");
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String request, Session session) {
    logger.info(session.getId() + " sent message : " + request);
}

@OnError
public void onError(Session session, Throwable t) {
    logger.error("Error !", t);
}

}
```

Here are the librairies I used :

[image]

Comment: The reason is obvious, as stated by Jur Clerkx in his answer. The `while(true) {}` is a spinlock, and I don't know where you got the idea to use that, but stop it. If you remove the `while`, does the program stop running?

Comment: Yes it does stop if there is no while.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit on the while loop that keeps your server running. Because of this, the full cpu usage goes to making this as fast as possible, while nothing is happening. I'm pretty sure adding `Thread.sleep(5)` would solve the problem. Fixed it most of the times I needed to make a server that listened for a socket. However, I don't know if this is best practice.

Comment: It's not. I would wager that `Server` starts a non-daemon thread that will keep the program running until the server is shut down.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, maybe it's not the best practice but at least it worked :)

Comment: @Phoste When you decide to read the documentation before writing bad code, here's a good place to start: https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.0/user-guide.html#standalone-mode

Comment: @Kayman It could be that 'Server' starts a non-daemon thread. But I'm pretty sure all the cpu usage is caused by the 'while(true)' loop, just because it can take full cpu usage without any limitations there.